# Using grails statement inside script tags

Tags: javascript, grails

Can I use grails statement as shown below:

```
<script>
    var opt = "Frederik";
    var check = ${com.mytest.User?.findByName(opt)};
</script>
```

Here what I am trying to do is, checking if the value is found in user table, if the value is found, I want to put value opt to all the `li` elements in HTML.

But the above statement does not recognize the opt.

Answer (score 4):

Modify your statement like this:

```
var check = ${com.mytest.User.findByName(opt) ? true : false};
```

`?` not required since `User` domain class can't be null as the app won't bootstrap until the class is missing.

Also, you don't need the `findBy` query since `countBy` is sufficient only for the check:

```
var check = ${com.mytest.User.countByName(opt) ? true : false};
```

Comment: +100000 for findBy/findAllBy -> countBy for cases like this. This is one of many often small optimizations that can certainly add up depending on usage to be a big performance and scalability boost

Comment: Thanks @BurtBeckwith :)